# Source transformation problem

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have this problem with a source transformation sum that I can't find the answer to. What do I do after these steps?

The question: 
[image]

My solutions:
[image]

Can it be as simple as algaebric addition of the voltage sources? if so, how do i take the v.s. in the right into account?

Answer (score 1):

In general you could use superposition** but in this case it's much simpler because the two supplies happen to end up being the same. 15V with 2\$\Omega\$  in series and 15V with 5\$\Omega\$ in series, which is equivalent to a single 15V supply with 5\$\Omega\$ || 2\$\Omega\$ =  1.43\$\Omega\$ in series, so the current is 15V/(1.43\$\Omega\$+7\$\Omega\$) = 1.78A

** Replace one voltage source with a short and calculate the current resulting from the other voltage source (1.27A), repeat with the other voltage source (0.51A). Add the two currents for the same result.